# Implementing Sign in with google on react native application with PHP Sociallite laravel backend

Tags: laravel, react-native, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm trying to implement a sign in with google button on a react native application, there is 0 documentation nor any help online with my scenario, there are only firebase examples.

This already works perfectly on React js app, everything is configured correctly, however on the react native app, I'm just stuck with a library that takes the client ID, I recieve authUserCode, and some other google credentials, but no redirects occur, normally on the react js, it redirects to another url, and to the backend and retrieves the token and saves it as a cookie. How can I continue with this on react native? should I call the redirect url manually?

Laravel with Socialite on the backend, react native on the front end, callback function and url work perfectly.

I had developer error on react-native-google-signin, but was solved when adding localhost to authorized javascript origins. Can someone explain this

Answer (score 1):

in react native you can't use cookie, so use AssyncStorage for save state of new user, and when you use google login in react native you may set firebase:

1. create new project
   2- create android application in your firebase
   project
   3- when you try number 2 : enter your package name
   correctly, be careful! and enter your application SHA1 code.
   3-1- for getting SHA1 code go to the android studio, in right side, click
   on Gradle>Tasks>android>signingReport  double click on
   signignReport.
   3-2- in the Terminal ( of android studio ) you should see SHA1 codes, don't hurry, Look for

Task :app:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug

copy their SHA1 code and go back to the firebase.

4- enter your SHA1 code and create application, in the next firebase gives you a file, google-services.json.
4-1- download the file and copy it to android>app in your project.

your firebase set is complete.

These steps will allow us to return to your application when the validation is complete.